# Google Drive API - Watch notifies "sync", but nothing after that

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I'm trying to subscribe to changes in a Team Drive folder or its direct-children files. I get a notification with X-Goog-Resource-State: sync, but no notifications after that. I've tried renaming files, editing file contents, adding/removing files. Nothing triggers additional notifications.

I'm doing this with the Ruby API:

```
drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
drive.authorization = ... # json auth for a service account with access to the drive
file_id = ... # id of the folder to watch
channel = {
  id: 'test',
  type: 'web_hook',
  address: 'https://example.com/notifications',
}
drive.watch_file(file_id, channel, supports_team_drives: true)
```

I know that this auth can list and access files within the team drive without problem. I get no errors from the watch_file call. I get the "sync" event successfully, but no "update" or similar events later.

Am I missing something? How can I debug this?

Comment: Did you follow the [Drive API Push Notifications guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#creating-notification-channels)?

Comment: Yes. Is there some step you feel I've missed?